# If $AB = BA$, how are the eigenvalues of $A$ related to those of $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two symmetric real square matrices, such that $AB = BA$. If $\lambda_{1},\dotsc,\lambda_{n}$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, can we find the eigenvalues of $B$?

Comment: As noted in the answers, you can't say anything interesting about the eigenvalues. However, under the conditions you listed, $A$ and $B$ can be simultaneously diagonalized, and you are guaranteed a basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in which every element of the basis is an eigenvector for both $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ can be any values. Just let $A$ and $B$ be diagonal matrices.

Answer (score 0):

What can you conclude if $A$ is the $0$ matrix?

Answer (score 0):

No. For simplicity, just use $A$ and $B$ diagonal matrices, so the diagonals are the eigenvalues. Then, with $\mu_i$ being the eigenvalues of $B$, you get $AB=BA$, since they are both diagonals, with $\lambda_i\mu_i$ on the diagonal. The above holds for **any** $\mu_i$